# .NET 7.0 - Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData - Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An OData version of 4.01 was specified

Tags: .net, .net-7.0, microsoft.aspnetcore.odata

I'm facing challenges while configuring the OData version in ASP.NET Core 7.0 with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData version 8.2.4`. I want to specify OData version 4.01, but despite my attempts, the configuration doesn't seem to be recognized correctly.

I got the error :

> Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An OData version of 4.01 was specified
> and the maximum supported OData version is 4.0.

Here is a snippet from my Startup.cs file:

```cs
services.AddControllers()
.AddOData(
  opt => {
    opt.Select().Filter()
    .OrderBy().Expand()
    .Count().SetMaxTop(null)
    .AddRouteComponents("odata",GetEdmModel());
  }
);
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights on how to correctly specify OData version 4.01 with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData version 8.2.4` in ASP.NET Core 7.0?

Thanks